# HTML5 Canvas: Get rect coords after rotation (relative to screen)

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas

```
update: function(delta) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.bullets.length; i++) {
        this.bullets[i].velocity = this.bullets[i].speed * delta;
        this.bullets[i].contextX += this.bullets[i].velocity;
    }
},

draw: function(ctx) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.bullets.length; i++) {
        ctx.save();

        // Move the context to where the player is then make it face the target degree
        ctx.translate(this.bullets[i].startX, this.bullets[i].startY);
        ctx.rotate(this.bullets[i].rotation);

        ctx.fillRect(this.bullets[i].contextX, -5, 10, 10);
        ctx.restore();
    }
}
```

The code above contains two methods that describe a class that manages the drawing and updating of bullets. The update method moves a bullet along and the draw function then draws it to the screen.

The canvas does the following:

1. Saves the current canvas context state
2. Moves the context to where the bullet originated from
3. Rotates the canvas to the way the bullet was facing when shot
4. Draw the rectangle
5. Restore the canvas context to original state

Here is an image I have made that better describes what the canvas context is doing:

[image]

So we know the x position of the bullet but this is relative to the context as it's been rotated. What I need to know is the bullet's X and Y properties in relation to the actual screen. Any ideas as to how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can calculate the untransformed canvas screen position of your rotated bullet like this:**

This function uses some trigonometry to get the bullet angle before and after rotation and it uses pythagora's theorm to calculate how far the bullet is from the player.

```
function bulletXY(playerX,playerY,bulletX,bulletY,rotation){
    var dx=bulletX-playerX;
    var dy=bulletY-playerY;
    var length=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    var bulletAngle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
    var screenX=playerX+length*Math.cos(bulletAngle+rotation);
    var screenY=playerY+length*Math.sin(bulletAngle+rotation);
    return({x:screenX,y:screenY});
}
```

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/EDk9W/

[image]

Comment: Dude, this is absolutely legendary. Is there a name for what you've done here so I can read more about it and try and get my head around it? Maybe a book you read or something? If you could help me try to understand how you worked this out I'd really appreciate it! Thanks so much!!! :-)

Comment: You're welcome!  Actually this is some Trigonometry--nothing legendary :)  Here's a fairly in depth blog post to get you started:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/35866/trigonometry-for-game-programming-part-1  Good luck with your project...Cheers!

Comment: One other thing, I see that this uses the player's position, why is this needed if I'm trying to get the bullet's on-screen position only?

Comment: You need to know the rotation point (in your case this is the player's position).  That's because context.rotate will rotate around that rotation point.  Think of the rotation point like a pencil point that you've pushed into a piece of paper.  All the objects on the paper will rotate around that pencil point as you rotate the paper.

Comment: What if say there were 4 players, how would that work then? Would the rotation point have to be relative to the player that shot the bullet? Just trying to think about simple collision detection in my head using this method, seems like it requires a lot of data just to figure where the bullet is

Comment: Well, I don't know your design, but yes, if a player is shooting a bullet then the origin (rotation point) would be that player.  So if multiple players are shooting, then their bullets must be tracked from each player's origin.